# Expected Expression Error xCode for iOS

Tags: objective-c

I get an xCode error for "Expected Expression" on the last line for ]];

```
[[sections addObject: @[@"Section",
                      @[@"Videos", @"YOUTUBE", @"UClNZzDwpw3jSjf8bWCMkvrg" ],
                      @[@"Twitter", @"TWITTER", @"TheMC_OG"],
                      @[@"Facebook", @"FACEBOOK", @"1450927785128543" ],
                      @[@"Instagram", @"INSTAGRAM", @"1468344498"]],
                      @[@"Whiskey Ducks", @"WEB", @[@"http://WhiskeyDucks.us" ]],
                      @[@"Apparel", @"WEB", @[@"http://GcpMC.Spreadshirt.com" ]],
]];
```

Im new to Coding and need help fixing this.

[here is the full code if you need](https://pastebin.com/E2VXjEZd) it in universal Config.m

Comment: Do it piece by piece. Rewrite it yourself. You'll see that are are the first `[` and last `]` shouldn't be there. You can compare it to the next `[section addObject:...]` just after

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
[sections addObject:@[@"Section",@[@"Videos", @"YOUTUBE", @"UClNZzDwpw3jSjf8bWCMkvrg" ],@[@"Twitter", @"TWITTER", @"TheMC_OG"],@[@"Facebook", @"FACEBOOK", @"1450927785128543"],@[@"Instagram", @"INSTAGRAM", @"1468344498"],@[@"Whiskey Ducks", @"WEB"], @[@"http://WhiskeyDucks.us"],@[@"Apparel", @"WEB"], @[@"http://GcpMC.Spreadshirt.com"]]];
```

Comment: Great :) You can show your support by accepting my answer :-)

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what the problem was.